# Why didn't the T-1000 terminator shoot the eyes of the T-800?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-2-judgment-day

In the first fight between the T-1000 and the T-800 in the back hallways of the shopping mall, why didn't the T-1000 use his pistol to shoot out the eyes of the T-800?

Fast forward to 1:40 in this video clip.

A blind T-800 would be vulnerable and unable to protect anybody.

The T-1000 shot the T-800 several times but didn't take a second to aim any better than hitting the chest. Surely it has better aim than that!

Comment: Mullets. So many mullets.

Comment: I have no evidence for this so, comment, but such an obvious weakness would make the t-800 a trivial threat. I would assume they had some sort of protection against that kind of attack.

Comment: In regards to your question, it seems like the T-1000 is aiming for John Connor at all times. When the T-800 begins shooting the shotgun the T-1000 doesn't really have time to regain balance enough to aim for the face. It could also be that the T-1000 programming is to kill John Connor making aiming for the eyes of another Terminator irrelevant to a certain extent. I'm interested to see if there is an appropriate in universe answer.

Comment: Because it would be a dick move Rich, a dick move. Like why would anyone do that? It's almost as bad as hitting someone in the genitals to win a fight.

Comment: @ArvinGBorkar Who thinks terminators are going to fight fair? Any move that allows them to win a fight is a move they will make. Fairness is not part of their programming.

Comment: Rich: Because it is not obviously done in the move. Well that and because shooting at a chest, as opposed to the head, is a better means of hitting something. The T-1000 cannot hone in on targets such as eyes, just for the sake of trying to disable its opponent. During that time, it was trying to kill John, being shot at, and shooting back to disable the T-800 all at the same time. 

Is there anything that suggests Terminators can hone in and shoot very well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hitting the eyes wont necessarily blind it. Remember Kyle Reese shot the first terminator in the eye, and its exoskeleton socket was undamaged.

> •During the chase in the car lot, Kyle scored a lucky hit to the T-800's face, a shard piercing its left eye, and the T-800 eventually had to remove the gelatinous covering. Its optical receptor, however, remained intact. - http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/T-800

Comment: There is further information about T-800 eye protection further down on the link you provided. ;-)

Comment: Rich: It just says "concussion-proof" and nothing about continuing to hit the same spot over and over again. Something concussion proof would mean if shaken, not directly hit.